# A question on Intermediate Microeconomics: A Modern Approach 9ed by Hal Varian, Section 14.6 Quasilinear Utility

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-surplus

In this section, there are two parts which I do not quite understand.

The first one is

> In general the price at which a consumer is willing to purchase some
> amount of good 1 will depend on how much money he has for consuming
> other goods. But in the special case of quasilinear utility the reservation prices are independent of the amount of money the consumer has to spend on other goods

What I understand is that when the utility function is quasilinear, $x_1^* = x_1(p_1,p_2)$ and $x_2^* = x_2(p_2, m)$. **Is it becaues $x_1^*$ does not depend on the income $m$, we say that "reservation prices are independent of the amount of money the consumer has to spend on other goods"?**

The second one is

> Economists say that with quasilinear utility there is “no income
> effect” since changes in income don’t affect demand. This is what
> allows us to calculate utility in such a simple way

I know that quasilinear utitliy implies that there is no income effect on Good 1. But **why does this allow us to calculate utility in such a simple way? If Good 1 can be affected by income effect, what will happen?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it becaues $x_1^*$ does not depend on
> the income m, we say that "reservation prices are independent of the amount of money the consumer has to spend on other goods"?

Exactly.

> But why does this allow us to calculate utility in such a
> simple way? If Good 1 can be affected by income effect, what will
> happen?

The point of quasilinear utility is that the consumer's decision on how much to buy of $x_1$ depends on the price $p1$ *only*, which simplifies the optimality condition. Eventually, this makes calculating the utility in the optimum also easier. I find the quote a bit strange, though, because one is usually interested in the utility-maximizing choice and not the level of utility associated with this choice.